# python: xgboost parameters overfitting

Tags: python, regression, boosting

I am using the xgboost regression algorithm to predict a continuous variable.
after splitting the data between train and test, I kept changing the xgb parameters to obtain the best possible predictive for both train and test, but it looks like that while the model has learned the train data very well, the same model applied to the test data shows a lower correlation, implying that the model overfits the data.
the following parameters

```
xgb.XGBRegressor( n_estimators= 200, max_depth=9, eta= 0.1, colsample_bytree= 0.8, subsample= 0.8)
```

show a correlation in the training set of roughly 0.8
but the same model applied to the testing set shows an r^2 of 0.6

Any suggestion in how to handle these parameters?

One more question: when calculating the mean squared error, I get for both train and test data a result that is very close to zero, which I assume is good, but judging by the scatterplot between predicted and actual, plenty of values do not follow the straight line. Any idea why ?

Comment: While I do occasionally, I'm not really all that keen on downvoting questions. But there isn't much to work with here so I'd recommend adding detail to your question. For example, we don't know if the size of your data is small. The scatterplot of MSE would be useful. All that said, it's normal for test results to be lower than train.

Comment: the dataset is very large. is close to  1mil rows. I know that is normal for the test to be lower than the train, but here i am talking about a 20% discrepancy. is that normal?

Comment: It can be but it does make me wonder. Since you have 1M rows, consider a train, validate, test split.

Comment: Hundreds of posts about your first question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=overfitting+%5Bboosting%5D Regarding your second question, it would be helpful if you posted a plot showing the behavior you describe.